# How to include a function expression return value based on a script argument

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I have a **Jenkins monorepo pipeline for an Angular project using nrwl/nx**.

I'm **trying to use the `npx nx affected:build`** command to build affected changes for the project apps / libs.

I **need to populate the --baseHref based on a dynamic value based on the project name**.
In the below example a `APPS_BASE_HREF` enumeration value based on the current `project.name` property.

It seems this approach does not work.
The function expression returns `null`, it does not resolve to the enumerator value.
I'm grooved up with trying! :)

The command resolves into :
`nx run app2:build:development --baseHref=null`

```
APPS_BASE_HREF = [
  'app1': '/test/app1',
  'app2': '/test/app2'
]

def getBaseHref(project){
    return APPS_BASE_HREF.get(project);
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    stages {
         stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh "npx nx affected:build --base=origin/develop --base-href ${getBaseHref("{project.name}")}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When modifying the `getBaseHref` function to :

```
def getBaseHref(project){
    return project
}
```

The command does seem to recognize the `project` value, and resolves into :

`nx run app2:build:development --baseHref=app2`

Anybody ... any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like the value you are passing is incorrect, it should be `${getBaseHref(project.name)}`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, the `""` was indeed a silly mistake. Removed them. Still does not seem to be working. Echo'ing the input `project` is typeOf `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2`. Not sure how to proceed. Any advice?

Comment: Where is the `project.name` defined?

Comment: The `project.name` is a expression argument provided by the `npx` command when ran. Trying to capture this inside the Groovy function as key to fetch from the `APPS_BASE_HREF` Enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided, due to reason that I didn't find a way to solve the above, to step away from the `sh "npx nx affected:build --base=origin/develop --base-href ${getBaseHref("{project.name}")}"` command approach.

I have simply added a function to return the affected projects, an Array, which I loop and build a seperate `sh` command for. Through this iteration, I'm able to put the right variables into place.

The outcome of this approach is the same, just requires some extra lines of code. Not a blocker.

```
/**
 * Get list of affected resources.
 *
 * @param target Select the specific target (build | test)
 * @param select Select the subset of the returned json document (e.g., --selected=projects)
 *
 * @return Array List of affected items
 */
def getAffected(String target = 'build', String select = 'tasks.target.project') {
    def affected = sh(script: "npx nx print-affected --base=${LAST_COMMIT} --head=HEAD --plain --target=${target} --select=${select}", returnStdout: true)
    return affected.replaceAll('[\r\n]+', '').split(', ')
}




stage('build') {
    steps {
        script {
            def affected = getAffected()
            for (int i = 0; i < affected.size(); ++i) {
                sh "npx nx run ${affected[i]}:build:production --base-href ${APPS_BASE_HREF.get(affected[i])}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```